# Pagodabox - Laravel4 setting different database provider

Tags: laravel-4, database-connection, pagoda-box

I'm using pagodabox for hosting my laravel 4  application  and I'm using my database from different hosting website everything is working great as long as I'm working locally

Once I switch to the live app I'm getting this error for example when I'm trying to log in

> QLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'claire.bradoseusers' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `bradoseusers`
>   where `Email` = ? limit 1)

`claire` is the default database that comes with pagodabox apparently it didn't recognize my database that configured in `config/database.php`

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => isset($_SERVER['DB1_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['DB1_HOST'] : 'ee2fb886-ff12-48f4-979c-a24e00dfa38c.mysql.sequelizer.com',
        'database'  => isset($_SERVER['DB1_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['DB1_NAME'] : 'dbee2fb886ff1248f4979ca24e00dfa38c',
        'username'  => isset($_SERVER['DB1_USER']) ? $_SERVER['DB1_USER'] : 'username',
        'password'  => isset($_SERVER['DB1_PASS']) ? $_SERVER['DB1_PASS'] : 'password',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

is there any extra configuration needed to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses PDO. Did you configure your .box file for this?

Add:

```
php_extensions: [pdo_mysql]
```

More info [here](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=190)

Comment: yes here's my boxfile

global:
  env:
    - LARAVEL_ENV: production
web1:
  name: bradose4
  shared_writable_dirs:
    - /storage/cache
    - /storage/database
    - /storage/logs
    - /storage/sessions
    - /storage/views
    - /storage/work
  document_root: /public
  php_version: 5.3.8
  php_extensions:
    - pdo_mysql
    - mcrypt
    - eaccelerator
    - memcached
    - curl
  before_deploy:
    - "php artisan migrate:install"
    - "php artisan migrate"
  after_deploy:
    - "rm -f storage/cache/*"
    - "rm -f storage/views/*"